# How to add request-reply scope to the mule studio 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

How to add request-reply scope to the mule studio 3.5.0. Not able to see request-reply scope in the pane. could you please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

The studio version you are referring to seems to be pretty old.Would be great if you could update to 5.X.

You may also try modifying the xml explicitly, in case you are deploying the code on a decoupled EE server.

```
<request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply"/>
```

Comment: Yes. we can do in xml . but I want to add request-reply scope in the studio. How I need to do? is there any possible to add in same studio?

Comment: is it possible to add as plugin? if yes .could u plz provide me the link to add?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/request-reply-scope) says that:

> The Request-Reply scope has been available since Mule Runtime version
>   3. An icon was added for this in the 3.5 version of Anypoint Studio

So in order for you to get an icon you need to install the 3.5 or above version of Anypoint Studio.